Clear button not visible on Fiori element APP with odata V4
I am comparing oData V2 and V4 for futur app using Fiori element tool.
For the V4 application I created, it shows the filterbar and I added the configuration in my manifest.json for a clear button as follow but it doesn't work :
Screenshot
Any advice ?
I tried several parameters to set the button visible through the manifest.json. None is working.
I expect a clear button for the filter bar.
